# Azure Table storage - Trying to GetEntity returns error message CS0311

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I have the following method:

```
   public async Task<Boolean> MarkAsProvisioned( string requestId)            
    {           
        try
        {
            //populate the connection object: 
             GetStorageAccountConnectionData();
            //lookup the record we need to change by the requestId.  
            var serviceClient = new TableServiceClient(
                new Uri(connection.storageUri),
                new TableSharedKeyCredential(connection.storageAccountName, connection.storageAccountKey));
            var tableClient = serviceClient.GetTableClient(connection.tableName);
            Azure.Response<Widget> response = tableClient.GetEntity<Widget>(
                                "mypartitionKey",
                                requestId);
            Widget entity = response;
            
            return true;

        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I'm getting the error on the line where I'm calling GetEntity().  The error is :

The type 'MyProject.Models.Widget' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'TableClient.GetEntity(string, string, IEnumerable, CancellationToken)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'MyProject.Models.Widget' to 'Azure.Data.Tables.ITableEntity'.csharp(CS0311)

I'm trying to do something like this:  (Pseudocode)

```
Widget entity = table.GetEntity<Widget >(partitionKey, rowKey);
entity.Name = newMessage;

table.UpdateEntity(entity, ETag.All, TableUpdateMode.Replace);
```

I can't see where I've gone wrong.

**EDIT 1**

This was the old class

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;

namespace MyProject.Models
{

    public class Widget
  {
    

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "requestId")]
     public string requestId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "status")]
    public string status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "request")]
    public WidgetRequest { get; set; }
  }
```

this is the new:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Azure.Data.Tables;
using System;
using Azure;

namespace MyProject.Models
{

    public class Widget:ITableEntity
  {
    public string PartitionKey { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public string RowKey { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public DateTimeOffset? Timestamp { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public ETag ETag { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "requestId")]
     public string requestId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "status")]
    public string status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "request")]
    public WidgetRequest { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: Does your `Widget` class implement `ITableEntity` interface? Please edit your question and include the code for `Widget` class?

Comment: @GauravMantri please see edit 1.  Updating the code now to see if it works with the interface implemented.

Comment: That did the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you [Gaurav Mantri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188096/gaurav-mantri) and [dot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1078009/dot) posting your discussions as answer to help other community members.

> add `ITableEntity` interface in `Widget` class to resolve the issue

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Azure.Data.Tables;
using System;
using Azure;
namespace MyProject.Models
{
public class Widget:ITableEntity
{
public string PartitionKey { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
public string RowKey { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
public DateTimeOffset? Timestamp { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
public ETag ETag { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "requestId")]
public string requestId { get; set; }
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "status")]
public string status { get; set; }
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "request")]
public WidgetRequest { get; set; }
}
```